# Velocity of a spacecraft in a circular orbit

Tags: homework-and-exercises

What is a formula for velocity of a spacecraft in a circular orbit?

Also, on side note, is there a formula or I can find it from equation of motion?

Comment: Your question seems to be under-defined.  What are you asking?  Is this just a homework-like question or is there some underlying concept to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is $\sqrt{\frac {GM}{r}}$ , where $M$ is the mass of the body(Earth) the spacecraft is revolving around, $r$ is the distance from the center of that body(Earth), and $G$ is the universal gravitational constant.

This can be easily derived from equating centripetal acceleration and gravitational attraction, i.e. $$\frac {mv^2}{r} = \frac {GMm}{r^2}$$

Note: this is only applicable for spherical bodies.

Comment: For attractive body or moving body? In this case, moving body is spacecraft. I don't know if it has to be spherical. Attractive body is the Earth.

Comment: The attractive body(earth) has to be spherical, or else you couldn't use $\frac {GMm}{r^2}$ for the gravitational attraction.

Comment: It's also a good approximation around non-spherical attractors as long as the orbital radius is large compared to the size of the attractor (i.e. you approximate the attractor as a point mass).

Comment: I thought about that, but then there would be no significance of the velocity, as $\frac Mr \to 0$